# IntelliJ - Unnecessary 'null' check before equals

Tags: java, intellij-idea

All of a sudden [[image]intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) is giving me warning / hints on code like this:

```
if (header != null && header.equals(PROXY_REQUEST_VALUE)) {
    // ...      
}
```

The hint says:

> Unnecessary 'null' check before equals()

And the little lamp solution changes the code to

```
if (PROXY_REQUEST_VALUE.equals(header) {
    // ...
}
```

I don't like [Yoda conditions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/). How do I disable the 'feature'?

---

Version is: `Ultimate 2017.1.6`

Comment: Well the second version does the exact same thing as the first one. It is also quicker to read. Why don't you like it?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but you can also use `Objects.equals(header, PROXY_REQUEST_VALUE)` to prevent a null check.

Comment: The second version saves you from an accidental Null Pointer Esception. So, its a good habit to always do `CONSTANT.equals(nonConstant)`.

Comment: In addition to S.D.'s comment: it only works if your constant is not null. But hey, did you have seen a constant which is null? If you do, then you are facing a bad coding decision.

Comment: Agreed with @S.D. it is better practice

Comment: @Bentaye agree with you all, but it's a matter of readability. You check a variable against a constant, not the other way around

Comment: @Ivar good one. Might actually start using it sometimes

Comment: The second way is correct, always check your constant (or string literal) first, this way no null check is required and you still avoid an NPE. IntelliJ isn't lying to you :-) In a code review I would call out the first way as not correct.

Comment: @Micheal future readers and younglings should follow what you all say. I'm sticking to my way though since, as I pointed out, I believe it's the right way to do it. Thank you all

Comment: @Michael of course IntelliJ ain't lying to me. I'm just surprised that it started giving the hint out of nothing while that code has been there for a while. Also I started seeing the `CONST.eq(var)` pattern at most a few years ago. How can it be seen as not correct?

Comment: @MarkoPacak "someString".equals(variable) is indeed correct. I didn't say anything different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ preferences, Editor > Inspections. You can use the search field in order to find the desired inspection more easily.

[image]

Comment: If you are not able to find that specific rule, place your cursor on the higlightened text, click on the bulb. It opens a menu. Use your arrow keys to navigate to the "edit inspection profile setting". This brings you to the relevant setting.

Comment: Specifically, the `Unnecessary 'null' check before 'equals() call'` checkbox. It is not explicitly stated in your answer, some people might not get it straight away

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[image]

preferences -> editor -> inspections -> java -> code style issues -> expression equals...

Comment: might be this one, but it was unchecked in my IDE whereas the one in the accepted answer was checked. someone should verify test yours as well